# Answer deleted with no reason

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers

I wrote an answer on this question: [MongoDB Fetching documents slow (Indexing used)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56805340) a few months ago and someone has deleted it.
I would like to know why because for me my answer is well related to the question.

**Even if people are wrong, a short message to tell them why it's not the correct way to solve the problem is the minimum when they take time to answer ...**

*Here is my answer:*

> I had the same problem, I was fetching around 35000 documents. I used
>   the aggregate function (*sakulstra:aggregate*) and in my case it has
>   incredibly boosted the request. The result format is obviously not the
>   same, but it's still easy to use to compute all things I need.
>
> Before (7000ms) :
>
> ```
> const historicalAssetAttributes = HistoricalAssetAttributes.find({
>         date:{'$gte':startDate,'$lte':endDate},
>         assetId: {$in: assetIds}
>     }, {
>         fields:{
>             "date":1,
>             "assetId":1,
>             "close":1
>         }
>     }).fetch();
> ```
>
> After (300ms):
>
> ```
> const historicalAssetAttributes = HistoricalAssetAttributes.aggregate([
>         {
>             '$match': {
>                 date: {'$gte': startDate, '$lte': endDate},
>                 assetId: {$in: assetIds}
>             }
>         }, {
>             '$group':{
>                 _id: {assetId: "$assetId"},
>                 close: {
>                     '$push': {
>                         date: "$date",
>                         value: "$close"
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     ]);
> ```

Comment: Moderator operating on auto-pilot, probably, didn't get past "I had the same problem".  One more undelete vote should restore the answer.

Comment: Undeleted now just few seconds before I went to cast a vote.

Comment: @HansPassant is the [answer timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56805340/timeline) accurate? It looks like it was review queue deleted

Comment: @SterlingArcher For me it reads like: Review queue complete with "no action needed" and half an hour later it got delete by a (at that) mod via (delete) vote. That "via vote" doesn't mean it is coming from a review queue.

Comment: @Tom I think I'm confused by how it reads, I thought the deleter wasn't a mod. But, that's aside the point, and doesn't really matter.

Comment: @SterlingArcher It went into the review queue as a late answer, which was marked no action needed. What you can't see is that there was also a "duplicate answer" flag, which is why it was deleted... this answer existed on three different posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767228/slow-meteor-fetch-after-quick-find/56805054#56805054 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878688/really-slow-fetch-in-meteor/56805184#56805184

Comment: @Catija that makes a lot more sense! That's definitely not visible from the timeline. I do appreciate you taking the time to explain though, thank you :)

Comment: I've duped the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42767228) to the one this answer was previously deleted on, to keep the comprehensive answers together.

Comment: [See this Meta.SE for why it's bad to post multiple identical answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: Many thanks you all for the answers !